# Cordova Google build error: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm getting a build error in cordova android 7.1.1 and now 8 when two or more Google Play plugins are installed, if the versions of google are 16.0.0:

`D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel`

I suspect it's Android X, but I thought that change was not breaking until v17.0.0 dependencies. I'm a bit lost.

The build works if I remove one of the plugins (I can build with either admob or analytics, but not both)

UPDATE: Looks like upgrading to cordova-android 9.0.0 solves that build problem. Cordova 9 supports AndroidX.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Cordova Android 9 solved the issue as it supports AndroidX. You do have to add  to the config.xml file.